# Bash how to add a sum of unknown numbers from a user

Tags: bash, unix, command

I have for example a user with a set of numbers. How can I make bash add them together?

Example in one go the user enters

(The amount of numbers they enter is up to them and it is unknown)

```
bash file 3 1 5 2 2 4
```

How can I make bash return 17 directly from that example?

I tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
sum=0
while read number && [ -n "$number" ]; do
    sum=$((sum + ${number/#-}))
    echo "$sum"
done
```

But this is not clean and it is returning

```
$ bash file
3
3
1
4
5
9
2
11
2
13
4
17
```

I instead want the user to only place their numbers in 1 go and not be there to put more and more numbers

Instead of having them excute the command like I  have it like

```
bash file
1
3
4
etc
```

instead I want to do it in 1 go

```
bash file 1 3 5 6
```

How?

Comment: The duplicate is for Java, but the answer is basically the same. `read` reads from standard input; you want to read the command-line arguments instead, which are in `"$@"` already when your script starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all script arguments and calculate `sum`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

sum=0
for i in "$@"; do
    sum=$(( $sum + $i ))
done
echo $sum
```

Running with your example:

```
$ bash sum 3 1 5 2 2 4
17
```